# Search data form CoreDataBase if search data similar with another data that contain special character

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, core-data-migration

I have implemented Core Database in my Application and fetching data from table.
Application requirement is fetch same data if **Data contain or not contain hyphen(-)**

For Exp1:
Table contain below data

```
   Id       Serialnumber     Name
   1          ABC          ABC2015
   2          A-BC         AB-C001
```

Table Column SerialNumber contain ABC, A-BC and if user search by **AB-C** is always consider same as ABC, A-BC

Exp 2:

```
Id    Serialnumber     Name
1        AB-C         AB-C2015
2        A-BC         A-BC001
```

Table Column SerialNumber contain AB-C, A-BC and if user search by **ABC** is always consider same as AB-C, A-BC

Here is my code

```
+(NSMutableArray*)fetchDataFromCoreDatabase:(NSString*)searchString {
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:k_CoreDBEnity_SerailnumerinManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Serialnumber == %@",searchString];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (error) {
    nslog(@"Unable to execute fetch request.");
    error, error.localizedDescription]];
}
return [result mutableCopy];}
```

So any ideas how to achieve this approach?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is "-" the only char "allowed" like this? If that's the case, I would add to your object an "cleanName" property, which holds the serialNumber (or name, depends on what you want) with only letters and numbers and perform the search on it?

Comment: Yes only "-" allowed @Larme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was me, I'd add an extra hidden field that would only be used for searching, which didn't include the hyphen. Then I would remove the hyphens before fetching. In your example:

- Add a field called something like `serialNumberSearch`. For your sample data this would always be "ABC", with no `-`.
- When searching, if I get `A-BC` or `AB-C`, first remove the `-` and then search for results that match the `serialNumberSearch` field.

The result will include anything that matches, according to your description.

Comment: Yes we can go with this approach, But How to Remove - in Table field data?
In Sql there a REPLACE function (SELECT REPLACE(string, string_to_replace, replacement_string) ) You have any idea how we can achieve this functionality  with Core Database

Comment: Change the string before inserting it. String has lots of methods for changing the contents of a string.

Comment: I implemented this approach and its work fine. Once I get good reputation I will up-voted this answers.